# Why don't auto height work on images?

Tags: javascript, css

What I am trying to accomplish is that, when you put an image on 100% it nicely scales the height accordingly. I like to catch that height and process it.

```
<div id="view" style="width:950px;">
    <img src="1.png" />
</div>
```

The image is 950x500pixels. However when I ask the view `$( '#view' ).height()` what the height is, it returns 16pixels. Does anyone know why it does this? Why doesn't it return 500pixels as that's the size of the image.

Comment: it depends on the structure of your html , can you post your html here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need image to be loaded first. Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <style>
    div { width: 950px; }
    img { width: 100%; }
  </style>
<body>
  <div>
    <img src="1.png">
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('img').load(function() {
      var height = $('div').height();
      console.log(height);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have test to alert the size of `<Div>` It's return the valid value, that return the size of image.

But from your code `$( 'view' ).height()` I have change to `$( '#view' ).height();`

Here is my code it's return correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loaded() {
            var height = $( '#view' ).height();

            alert(height);
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="loaded();">
        <div id="view" style="width:950px;">
            <img src="Desert.jpg" />
        </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use local image, you can use an image with URL, like "http://www.veryued.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/less-online.png".

Please read [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) carefully:

> Caveats of the load event when used with images:
>
> - It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
> - It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
> - Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

Comment: In the real code I have the entire path. This was just for sample purposes. Thanks never the less for the information, I didn't know it.